# Перезагрузка страницы без потери написанного в <textarea>

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажите, как можно сделать перезагрузку страницы так, чтобы в поле  остались уже написанные там символы! Нужна именно перезагрузка, как при нажатии F5, форма при этом не отправляется. Мне это надо для того, чтобы при диалоге с человеком можно было автоматически увидеть сообщение не перезагружая страницу вручную. Или вы можете посоветовать другие способы, без перезагрузки страницы полностью?

Comment: Нужна именно перезагрузка, т.е. как по нажатию F5? Форма при этом отправляется?

Comment: Как вариант: перед перезагрузкой сохранять это в `localstorage`

Comment: @AresGod вопрос на какое событие это повесить, ведь можно нажать F5 во время заполнения формы.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, `onkeyup` отлично для этого подойдет

Comment: можно сохранение положить в обработчик window.onUnload , 
window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант - сохранять данные в `localStorage` при `onunload` или `onkeyup`:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myText");

element.value = restoreValue("myText");
window.onunload = () => keepValue(element); 

function keepValue(e){
  localStorage.setItem(e.id, e.value);
}

function restoreValue(item){
  if (localStorage.getItem(item) === null) {
      return "";
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(item);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

```js
document.getElementById("myText").value = restoreValue("myText");
function keepValue(e){
    localStorage.setItem(e.id, e.value);
}

function restoreValue(item){
    if (localStorage.getItem(item) === null) {
        return "";
    }
    return localStorage.getItem(item);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myText" onkeyup="keepValue(this);"></textarea>
```

Comment: Не создадут ли сотни сохранений в минуту слишком высокую нагрузку на комп?

Comment: @andreymal, можете протестить: https://jsperf.com/localstorage-performance

Comment: Cпасибо, именно второй ответ работает!